# Настоящее время глаголов совершенного вида

Tags: словообразование

Укажите ряд, где не от всех глаголов можно образовать форму 1 лица
настоящего времени.

1. ощущать, отереть, оторопеть, отдавить
2. очутиться, отучиться, отряхнуться, оформиться
3. ошеломить, оцепить, отмереть, отобрать
4. отглотнуть, отгостить, отогнуть, отозвать

От глаголов совершенного вида, как известно, настоящее время не образуется. В ответах дан ответ 2. Но и в других рядах глаголы не образуют настоящего времени, за исключением первого ряда, там есть глагол **ощущать.**

Comment: Серж, просмотрите повнимательнее свой вопрос! «Совершенного **времени**»  —  что это такое?

Comment: Слава, спасибо, что заметили. Конечно же, совершенного вида. Думаю одно,пишу другое.

Comment: Серж, Вы исправили на совершенный вид в тексте вопроса, нужно ещё исправить заголовок.

Comment: В этом тесте не настолько строго, что нельзя совершенную форму переделать в несовершенную.

Comment: То есть превратить, не образовать по законам словообразования. Вы слишком строги.

Comment: @oleed Если мы превратим, что изменится?

Comment: Тогда "От глаголов совершенного вида, как известно, настоящее время не образуется" можно проигнорировать.

Comment: Да, но и тогда задание не станет корректным. Ведь важно не то, что не образуется, а что задание некорректное.

Comment: Но мы же можем совершенную форму превратить в несовершенную.

Comment: Конечно, можем! Тогда кокой вы выберите?

Comment: Второй, как у Галины.

Comment: Ну и от второго можно образовать несовершенны вид: отучиваться, оформляться

Comment: От "очутиться" не получается, настоящего у него вообще нет: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/очутиться

Comment: От "отглотнуть" тоже невозможно.

Comment: "Отглатываю", https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/отглатывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нет такого варианта.**

В каждом ряду есть глаголы, которые не имеют формы 1-го лица настоящего времени.

Это или **все глаголы** (ряды 2, 3, 4, там все глаголы сов. вида) или **три глагола** (ряд 1, там три глагола сов. вида, и только глагол ***ощущать*** несов. вида).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148804/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Серж, как я понял, приведённое Вами задание – из армянского сборника «Проверка знаний учителя».

Вариантов причин появления задания с такой формулировкой у меня два: либо это ошибка авторов сборника, либо сознательное внедрение вопроса, на который невозможно ответить правильно, в тест с последующей проверкой реакции учителя на неграмотно сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: Раньше было армянское радио, а теперь армянские сборники.

Comment: @Буратино Да, это ошибка составителей) А армянское радио - это какое (очень заумное или что-то еще)? Я занималась с армянскими детьми, и они грамматику понимали прекрасно. Но были проблемы с художественной речью (не получалось составить текст).

Comment: @Sharon Вы не знаете, что такое "армянское радио"??) Так обычно начинались анекдоты содержащие абсурдные вопросы и ответы с юмором - "вопрос армянскому радио: почему.."

Comment: Слышала, что есть такое (в анекдотах). Я теперь вот думаю, почему? Они же очень умные (цепкий ум), говорят по-русски без акцента. Что же именно их выделили, а не кого-то еще?

Comment: Пишут такое: Как-то начале семидесятых в Москве, в Колонном зале Дома Союзов проходило Всесоюзное совещание работников радио и телевидения. Когда председательствующий объявил: «Слово предоставляется представителю армянского радио», в зале стоял такой хохот, что бедному представителю долго не давали начать выступление.
Когда смех, наконец, стих, этот самый представитель взял микрофон и произнёс: «Нас часто спрашивают...» Говорят, после этого работа совещания была полностью парализована.
Чаще всего армянское радио спрашивали о женщинах и о политике.

Comment: @,Слава, согласен, это ошибка составителей. Что они имели в виду, непонятно.

Comment: Да, это вопросы из добровольной аттестации учителей.

Comment: @Буратино  Тогда понятно: умные и находчивые  люди  с юмором отвечают на глупые вопросы.   Получается, что составители хотели подставить учителей или как?

Comment: @Sharon составители хотели, чтобы учителя проявили ум и находчивость.

Comment: @Буратино Интересно, проявили или нет?) Скорее всего – не все.

Comment: @Sharon,  скорее всего будут жалобы.

Answer (score 1):

Таки второй.

Дано:

1. ощущать, отереть, оторопеть, отдавить
2. очутиться, отучиться, отряхнуться, оформиться
3. ошеломить, оцепить, отмереть, отобрать
4. отглотнуть, отгостить, отогнуть, отозвать

---

(ПРЕ)образуем:

1. ощущаю, отираю, оторопеваю, отдавливаю

**2.** отучиваюсь, отряхиваюсь, оформляюсь, *но не **очучиваюсь***

3. ошеломляю, оцепляю, отмираю, отбираю
4. отглатываю, [отгащиваю](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&from=ru&to=xx&did=&stype=0), отгибаю, отзываю

Comment: Мне кажется, что в вопросе  какие-то проблемы с видовыми парами. Видовая пара: отереть (сов.) - отирать (несов.).  Буд. время: Я ототру (что сделаю).  Наст. время: Я отираю (что делаю)

Comment: Надо помнить, что для Сержа русский - иностранный. Я не стала углубляться в форму вопроса, отвечала на: ***В ответах дан ответ 2. Но и в других рядах глаголы не образуют настоящего времени...*** И честно образовывала ***форму 1 лица настоящего времени***. ОТГАЩИВАЮ меня шибко прикололо. )))

Comment: Смотрю словарь ОТОРОПЕТЬ, -ею, -еешь; св. Разг. Прийти в сильное замешательство, растеряться от чего-л. О. от неожиданности, от страха. О., увидев гостей.  А вот глагола несов. вида "оторопевать" у них нет. Значит, это не нормированная форма?

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/146102

Comment: Да, спасибо. У Ожегова глагол был, а у Кузнецова уже нет))  Вот и Буратино ругает это слово...

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, оттираю — от оттирать. Ошеломляю от ошеломлять. А не от: оттереть и ошеломить..

Comment: И да: для меня русский первый родной язык, армянский — второй. И мыслю я на русском, а не на армянском.

Comment: По приколу можно образовать "очутяюсь". В Гугле немного есть.

Answer (score 1):

Я напишу ересь. Но дело в том, что оторопеваю - это чушь бессмысленная, хотя я понимаю, что его включил в словарь Ожегов и далее повторила Ефремова и Шанский. Но дело в том, что оторопеть - это пассивное действие. Активное будет звучать как оторапливать - оторапливаю. У Даля вообще эта форма слова основная, а оторопить, оторопеть - это производные.

> ОТОРАПЛИВАТЬ, оторопить кого, заторопить, суетливою торопливостью
> сбить с толку, поставить в тупик. Оторопеть, оробеть, испугаться или
> потеряться, не найтись, не знать что делать, одуреть под внезапным
> страхом, от нечаянности, расплоха. Медведя исплошили, и тот оторопел,
> а человеку и Бог велел. Оторопенье ср. отороп муж. оторопь, оторопка
> жен. ·сост. по гл. О'тороп, оторопь напала, панический страх. Оторопь
> его взяла, оробел: пск. ·произн. оторок. Оторопелый, что без ума.
> Оторопелость жен. состоянье оторопелого. Оторопчивый, пугливый,
> робкий, легко торопеющий. Взять кого оторопом, оторопью, расплохом,
> внезапностью, испугав.

Оторопеваю употребил Евтушенко:

> — Это как? — оторопеваю я.

Но по идее он должен был сказать "оторопел я."

Я считаю, это ошибка логики словообразования, можно еще сказать криво-косо оторопеваюсь, но не оторопеваю.

То есть это как сказать: сбиваю я в тупик. Криво-косо можно сказать я сбился, сбиваюсь в тупик, но сбиваю я - это сбиваю другого.

Насчет "очутиться", да, нет формы очучаю, но есть будущая форма очучусь.

Потому что очутиться = это ощутить себя. Я ощущаю, я ощущу, я ощутил себя = я очутился.

Далее, как видно в других строках есть глаголы вида оцепить - оцепляю, то есть форма с Л. Хотя это не совсем производная оцепить, а скорее наоборот, оцепить - это производная оцеплять. Но видимо, это допустимо, а вот 2 строчка, видимо, выпадает.

Comment: Оторопел – "быстрое" действие, а оторопеваю – постепенно! И это сказал поэт Евтушенко. А Ожегова "задвинули" современные грамматики. Не ладно что-то в Датском королевстве.

Comment: Оторопеваю это вроде "туплю"? ) Нет, не тот суффикс совсем, так не получится, действие пассивное. Разложите слово на фразу - "сбивать с толку" -  и попробуйте применить те же суффиксы, получается чушь.

Comment: Что ж пробовать, надо с грамматикой разобраться.  Ну и с семантикой тоже, а то и с этимологией. Откуда словечко взялось, что за признак обозначало.

Comment: По Далю от оторапливать - заставлять суетиться и этим сбивать с мысли кого-то. Оторопеть - это пассивное действие или состояние того, кого оторопили, огорошили, ошарашили. Ну это уже я часть додумал)

Comment: @Sharon ну или банально - огорчаться, огорчаю - это огорчаю другого, а огорчаюсь - это сам. Оторопел - это какая-то форма разговорная, вроде фразеологизма. Ну или обледенел - обледеневаю(?), нет, леденею.

Comment: Значит, у Даля переходный глагол, это он пассивные конструкции образует. Кстати, обратить внимание на суффиксы Е/И:  обессилИть (кого-то) и обессилЕть самому.

Comment: @Sharon может, я пока не разбираюсь в переходности), а обессилеть - можно сделать форму настоящего времени?

Comment: Кузнецов разрешает: ОБЕССИЛЕТЬ, -ею, -еешь; св. Стать бессильным, ослабеть. О. от голода, болезни. О-ая дорогой, она в изнеможении опустилась на стул. Да вы совсем обессилели, что с вами? <Обессилевать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.

Comment: @Sharon Тогда форма ТОРОПЛЕЮ.)

Comment: Меня "оторопеваю"  больше устраивает.

Comment: @Буратино, ни у Ефремовой, ни у Ожегова я не нашел формы оторопеваю. Если она и есть, то уже образуется от глагола несовершенного вида: оторопевать.

Comment: У Ожегова указана видовая пара:  оторопеть – оторопевать. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/146102  Значение понятно: теряться – растеряться.   Но употребляется очень редко, например: Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015) 
Обычным порядком направляется к раковине, включает воду и смотрит на себя в зеркало. Оторопевает. На него глядит — нет, не чужое лицо.